# Error in running RSpec. 2.13.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, rspec-rails, ruby-datamapper

I have written a spec file for `update` function of one controller. I am using `ruby-1.9.3 p194`, `Rails 3.2.13` and `rspec 2.13.1` and `data mapper version ~> 1.2.0'`. I am calling `update` function in my spec as follows:

```
put :update, :id=>@xyz.id, :xyz=> {key1:val1, key2:val2}
```

In update function of my `xyz` controller I have accessed `id` as  follows:

```
def update
 params[:xyz][:id] = params[:id]  #This line is working fine and params[:id] is not nil
 params = params[:xyz]
 id = params[:id]               
end
```

Problem is that while I am running the same file without any change twice at a time, it is giving two different errors. Once it is giving the following error:

```
/home/joy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@packageName/gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-           
 core/collection.rb:1302: in resource undefined method 'saved?' for nil:NilClass 
(NoMethodError) 
....
```

Next time, while running, it is giving the following error:

```
NoMethodError:
  undefined_method 'id' for "57":string"
# ./app/controllers/xyz_controller.rb : in line number 3 of update where I am setting the id is giving error.
```

Is this the case the ruby version or the rspec or data-mapper version I am using is unstable or there is any other problem that I could not figure out. Please help.

Comment: rspec can't or doesn't read `params` in the same way your controller does - I'm not sure what you should be doing, but i've been struggling with this myself lately.

Comment: dax I have not read params in rspec but in controller.

Comment: right but this is the reason you're getting an error when running rspec

Comment: Could you please tell me how to fix this?